# Creating images and pushing services with volumes

Tags: mysql, wordpress, docker, docker-compose

I created and push to Docker Hub two images made with `docker tag`

```
REPOSITORY              TAG                   IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
wordpress               5.2.2-php7.1-apache   wordpress_image_id  2 weeks ago         438MB
username/repos          wordpress             wordpress_image_id  2 weeks ago         438MB
mysql                   5.7                   mysql_image_id      2 weeks ago         447MB
username/repos          mysql                 mysql_image_id      2 weeks ago         447MB
...
```

Then I changed the `docker-compose.yml` to pull and use those images

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  db:
    # image: mysql:5.7
    image: username/repos:mysql
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    # image: wordpress:5.2.2-php7.1-apache
    image: username/repos:wordpress
    ports:
      - "8010:80"
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    volumes:
      - ./wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content
      - ./uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
volumes:
  db_data: {}
```

Then later on, I stumbled upon `docker volume ls` and `docker volume prune` and gave those two a go, and now `localhost:8010` loads up Wordpress 5-min installation.  I tried `docker pull` my two images, and still it's the installation page.  This is actually fine, since I know I can restore it fairly quickly.

But my question is what is even uploaded in my pushed images?  Is all `docker tag` did is just copy the original images of `wordpress:5.2.2-php7.1-apache` and `mysql:5.7`?  If so, then how do I create images to reflect the changes I'm making on my local development, and use them in my local development and remote server on Vultr CentOS server?

Comment: Generally you [write a Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/) that bundles your application.  If you’re using a prepackaged application where you’re just configuring it, you need to manage the data (in volumes or host directories) separately; that never goes into an image and you can’t `docker push` your live data.

Comment: I see, can you show me an example of such dockerfile?  Also, does that make what I did with images unnecessary, meaning that no changes were necessary in my original `docker-compose.yml` file?

Comment: If you `docker tag`ged an existing image with a new name, and `docker push`ed the new name, then you just pushed an identical copy of the upstream image.  The Docker tutorial I linked to walks through packaging a simple Python application with a Dockerfile.